# Tensorflow: transferring variables across graphs

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to figure out how to import a learned saved model as a part of a larger model.

To be concrete, I have an RNN and some embedding matrices (model A) that have been trained on a large dataset stored in a `.ckpt` file. I also have another model (model B), that uses this exact same RNN and embedding model as a submodel, with additional ops to manipulate the output of this RNN and use it for classification.

The graph definitions for these two models are different, but I'd like to initialize model B to the saved version of model A.  How can this be done?

My attempt so far is to try and load model A as another model under a different session and graph and then assign the relevant matrices in model B to those from A, but this isn't working.

Here's the relevant portion of code:

```
sup = supervised() # spins up a class with an interactive session inside and sets up the graph
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    unsup = unsupervised('unsup.ckpt') # loads in model A from file 
                                       # w/ another session (not interactive)
    # get matrix from unsup and assign to sup
    sup._word_embeddings.assign(unsup.session.run(unsup._word_embeddings))
    # do the same for the RNN
    sup._gate_matrix.assign(unsup.session.run(unsup._gate_matrix))
    sup._gate_bias.assign(unsup.session.run(unsup._gate_bias))
    sup._cand_matrix.assign(unsup.session.run(unsup._cand_matrix))
    sup._cand_bias.assign(unsup.session.run(unsup._cand_bias))
```

Note that both models have explicit variables assigned to the matrices from `rnn_cell.linear` for the RNN using `tf.get_variable()` when instantiating the class.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be so easy.  This was just creating the assign ops... To actually do the assignment, run the ops in the appropriate session.

Comment: Hi, Could you share your solution ?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't have the code for this on hand anymore. Basically all of these assign ops are symbolic ops defined on `g`, so to run them, you need to run `g` in a `session.run`. Hope this helps.

Comment: What i intend to do is, to restore weights for two different model(which i consider as two different graphs), then i want the output of first to be the input of the second graph

Comment: If that's what you want, why not just restore the two graphs (call them `A` and `B`) and pipeline them. Eg, `A_out = session.run(A, {input:input}); B_out = session.run(B, {input:A_out})`. I know this is not ideal, but it could work as a stopgap until you figure out something better.

Comment: But I want the gradient flow between the graph, is that possible?